# How to show data related to that clicked li tab

Tags: jquery

During page load I am showing only 1D Data(Default data) , now when the user clicks on corresponding tabs how to show data related to it that particular clicked tab

my sample code

```
function fetchTopLosersData(tabclicked) {
    var htmldatafortoploosers = '';
    htmldatafortoploosers += '<thead><th class="thheaders">Symbol</th></thead><tbody>';
    if (tabclicked === '#1d') {
        for (var i = 0; i < samplejson1day.length; i++) {
            var symbol = samplejson1day[i].symbol;
            htmldatafortoploosers += '<tr> <td>' + symbol + '</td>';
        }
    } else if (tabclicked === '#1w') {
        for (var i = 0; i < samplejson1week.length; i++) {
            var symbol = samplejson1week[i].symbol;
            htmldatafortoploosers += '<tr> <td>' + symbol + '</td>';
        }
    }

    else if (tabclicked === '#2w') {
        for (var i = 0; i < samplejson2week.length; i++) {
            var symbol = samplejson2week[i].symbol;
            htmldatafortoploosers += '<tr> <td>' + symbol + '</td>';
        }
    }

     else if (tabclicked === '#3w') {
        for (var i = 0; i < samplejson3week.length; i++) {
            var symbol = samplejson3week[i].symbol;
            htmldatafortoploosers += '<tr> <td>' + symbol + '</td>';
        }
    }

    $(tabclicked).html(htmldatafortoploosers);
}
```

And this is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/13/

Could you please tell me how to show data related to that  tab only

Comment: is this what you want?? https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/gr1L23us/14/

Comment: yes that's what i wanted , thank you very much ...

Answer (score 0):

First find all `tab-content-1` in `tab-container-1` and hide them, after that show clicked menu's content on `ul.menu li` click like following.

```
$("ul.menu li").click(function() {
    var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $('.tab-container-1').find('.tab-content-1').hide().html('');
    $(tabclicked).show();
    fetchTopLosersData(tabclicked);
});
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/16/